# THREE.js line drawn with BufferGeometry not rendering if the origin of the line isn't in the camera's view

Tags: javascript, three.js, line

I am writing a trace-line function for a visualization project that requires jumping between time step values. My issue is that during rendering, the line created using THREE.js's BufferGeometry and the setDrawRange method, will only be visible if the origin of the line is in the camera's view. Panning away will result in the line disappearing and panning toward the origin of the line (usually 0,0,0) will make it appear again. Is there a reason for this and a way around it? I have tried playing around with render settings.

The code I have included is being used in testing and draws the trace of the object as time progresses.

```
var traceHandle = {
    /* setup() returns trace-line */
    setup : function (MAX_POINTS) {
        var lineGeo = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
        //var MAX_POINTS = 500*10;
        var positions = new Float32Array( MAX_POINTS * 3 ); // 3 vertices per point
        lineGeo.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(positions, 3));
        var lineMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color:0x00ff00 });  
        var traceLine = new THREE.Line(lineGeo, lineMaterial);
        scene.add(traceLine);
        return traceLine;
    },
    /****
    * updateTrace() updates and draws trace line
    * Need 'index' saved globally for this
    ****/
    updateTrace : function (traceLine, obj, timeStep, index) {
        traceLine.geometry.setDrawRange( 0, timeStep );
        traceLine.geometry.dynamic = true;
        var positions = traceLine.geometry.attributes.position.array;
        positions[index++]=obj.position.x;
        positions[index++]=obj.position.y;
        positions[index++]=obj.position.z;

        // required after the first render
        traceLine.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true; 
        return index;       
    }
};
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Likely, the bounding sphere is not defined or has radius zero. Since you are adding points dynamically, try `traceLine.frustumCulled = false;`

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply, that fixed the problem. What's the topic for the theory behind this so I can do some reading? (And how do I give you a tick)

Comment: Well, it is a matter of understanding the inner-workings of the library. The topic is frustum-culling. How that is handled is renderer-specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Likely, the bounding sphere is not defined or has radius zero. Since you are adding points dynamically, you can set:

```
traceLine.frustumCulled = false;
```

The other option is to make sure the bounding sphere is current, but given your use case, that seems too computationally expensive.

three.js r.73